# Disable resizing of gif when uploaded

Tags: filters, uploads, images

Animated gifs are getting more popular on the web (again) and currently there is no good tool for resizing animated gifs.

So I want to disable resizing/generation of image sizes for the gif mimetype and just save the original gif.

Someone that can help me out with this? Which filter to use will be a good start.

Comment: What if the gif is not animated? Where are you using the animated gifs: in the post editor or as a post thumbnail? Did you try searching this site?

Comment: @birgire It is for personal use, so I would not upload a gif without it being animated. I could also make a function that check if its animated. I'm going to use animated gifs both in the editor and thumbnails. The reason why I want this is if a specific image size for a thumbnail/image doesn't exist it will fall back to the original. This way if I don't have any other sizes of the gif, it will fall back to the original animated gif.  I tried searching the site and the codex, but have not found a clear answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

image_make_intermediate_size was not the hook I was looking for, but intermediate_image_sizes_advanced.

Here is a working code:

```
function disable_upload_sizes( $sizes, $metadata ) {

    // Get filetype data.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype($metadata['file']);

    // Check if is gif. 
    if($filetype['type'] == 'image/gif') {
        // Unset sizes if file is gif.
        $sizes = array();
    }

    // Return sizes you want to create from image (None if image is gif.)
    return $sizes;
}   
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'disable_upload_sizes', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

> currently there is no good tool for resizing animated gifs

Resizing of animated gifs is [supported by ImageMagick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257831/how-can-i-resize-an-animated-gif-file-using-imagemagick), which happens to be the default image library of WordPress. The only thing is WP doesn't support this filter in its default API to ImageMagick.

Fortunately, it is possible to intercept [`image_make_intermediate_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_make_intermediate_size), the hook that produces the resized images. Here you could intercept gifs and have them handled in a different way. Perhaps you could take inspiration from [this image sharpening plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sharpen-resized-images/) to see how to apply ImageMagick methods to your images.

Comment: yes `convert` is a great command line tool.

Comment: @birgire You mean it cannot be converted to work inside php?

Comment: I haven't thought about it from the PHP context, I just like to work on the Linux command line and there this tool is ideal ;-) I haven't checked recently how WP handles animated gifs, but It would be interesting to check if it's possible to extend the WP_Image_Editor_Imagick class if needed to support it. Maybe there're other ways to support it within WordPress?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397896/change-imagemagick-command-line-into-php-imagick) seems to suggest you can get `convert` working in php as well.

Comment: But for the purpose of OP building a fairly complex plugin to get this done is probably a bit too much.

Comment: @cjbj Thank you for your reply, the image_make_intermediate_size is the hook I was looking for! I have been looking into resizing animated gifs with ImageMagick earlier. I read that ImageMagick resize the animated gifs, but usually ends up with bigger file sizes than the original animated gifs. So it doesn't make any sense to resize if you end up with bigger file sizes. This information might be old though. 

Also, wordpress have been considering implementing resizing of animated gifs into the core: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28474