# WordPress theme logo handling (Trying to use GIF as logo)

Tags: themes, logo

I am trying to use a GIF as a logo on a WP site but all I can get is a still image. I read a lot about it and it seems the issue is that the theme resizes the GIF which destroys the animation.

Where can I find the logo size settings and is it enough to change them in a child theme or is there more to it?

I thought the logo settings chould be in the file `header.php` but my `header.php` is almost empty, with the exception of the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package vogue
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

// File Security Check
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

get_template_part( 'header-single' );
get_template_part( 'header-main' );
```

So I am back to square one. How can I locate and change the logo size settings?

Comment: This may help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229675/disable-resizing-of-gif-when-uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a theme-specific question it would be better to ask the theme's author/support team directly. As you can see from `header.php` your theme uses template parts. The `header-main.php` file is the most likely one to contain the logo since its name implies it would be used sitewide.

You are most likely looking for code that looks something like this:

`get_theme_mod('custom_logo'), 'medium')`

or

`if(has_custom_logo())`

or

`the_custom_logo()`

generally - something to do with `custom_logo`. When you find the call to `custom_logo` it will probably specify `medium` or some other image size. You want to change whatever image size the theme is using to `full` which in most cases will display the full, un-resized version you uploaded. Once you've done that, you may also need to edit some CSS since that can also affect the size the image is displayed at - though not the actual, underlying file.

Comment: And yes, creating a child theme to override only the files that refer to the logo is all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just want to ask: after setting the logo size to full, is it safe to resize it using CSS or will this still destroy the annimation as regular resizing does?

Comment: I found a file called Branding so I guess that should be it. In there I found the following line `$logo .= presscore_get_the_main_logo()` Is that it and what does it mean when no size is specified?

Comment: You should ask the theme developer. They've created their own functions so it's not something we can guess at here - though it does sound like you have probably found what you're looking for. Since they are not using any size their function probably won't accept one directly.